# Error in installing "TopicModels" package in Google Colab

Tags: r, google-colaboratory, topic-modeling

Since I need more computational resources, I started running my R code on Google Colab. I have no problem with installing most of the packages I need, but for the "TopicModels" package when I run the code below:

```
install.packages('topicmodels', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
```

I get the following error message on Google Colab:

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

Warning message in install.packages("topicmodels", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/"):
“installation of package ‘topicmodels’ had non-zero exit status”
```

Can anyone advise how I should resolve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running this in a code cell before the installation of the `topicmodels` package.

```
system2('sudo', 'apt-get install libgsl0-dev')
```

This installs a required library in the Unix environment of Colab that you would normally install from a command prompt like this.

```
sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev
```

In Python notebooks, you would do this.

```
!sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev
```

But this doesn't seem to work in R notebooks so the `system2` call does the work.

Comment: Thanks so much. This code worked, can you please tell me what exactly it's doing?